# How to implement fixed, readonly headers between paragraphs in draft.js?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

My editor is split into seperate "sections" eg

- History
- Examination
- Results
- Evaluation

which are edited seperately and different semantics (content type) affects functionality inside. Each section would be designated by Header (section title) and Content eg

> ### History
>
> ...text here...
>
> ### Examination
>
> ...text here...

The header has to be readonly so that it's content is not editable and header element itself can never be removed.

How would I implement this in draft.js?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use several draft instances. This does, however mean that they will have separate undo/redo stacks and copy/paste may not work as you expect.

The alternative solution would be to try to protect the headings, but it would require a lot of work, since you'd have to not only intercept when the user types normally, but also copy/paste and various other things.